# Can Monotone Class Theorem be easier to check than $\pi$-$\lambda$ Theorem?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I've been working on problem 14.4 in Billingsley's "Probability and Measure", which says:

> "Let $C$ be the set of continuity points of $F$. Show that for every Borel set $A$, $P(F(X) \in A, X \in C)$ is at most Lebesgue measure of $A$."

They also defined $\phi(u) = \inf \{x: F(x) \geq u \}$ in the chapter.

My instinct was to use the $\pi$-$\lambda$ system. I let the $\pi$ system be
\begin{align}
\mathcal{P}=\{(0,v)|v\in(0,1)\}
\end{align}
and showed that 
\begin{align}
P(F(X) \in (0,v), X \in C) = P(X \leq \phi^-(v), X \in C) = F(\phi^-(v)) \leq v=\lambda(0,v)
\end{align}
for all $v \in (0,1)$.

However, I got stuck when I tried to prove that

\begin{align}
\mathcal{L} = \{A \in \mathcal{B}(0,1) | P(F(X) \in A, X \in C) \leq \lambda(A) \}
\end{align}

is a $\lambda$ system. Specifically, I'm having trouble with checking that
\begin{align}
A, B \in \mathcal{L}, A \subset B \implies B \setminus A \in \mathcal{L}
\end{align}

Knowing that $P(F(X) \in A, X \in C) \leq \lambda(A)$ and $P(F(X) \in B, X \in C) \leq \lambda(B)$ doesn't seem to be enough to conclude that $P(F(X) \in B \setminus A, X \in C) \leq \lambda(B \setminus A)$.

The book's solution involved checking that $P(F(X) \in (u,v), X \in C) \leq v-u$, showing that $\{\text{finite disjoint unions of }[u,v)|0\leq u<v <1 \}$ forms a field, and using Halmos' Monotone Class Theorem. Could anyone please point out what I did wrong? I'm surprised that it's so much harder to solve this problem using $\pi$-$\lambda$ Theorem because I thought they were equivalent. Thank you in advance!

Comment: First of all, the set defined in the second solution is not a field (why?). Second, both theorems are equivalent, but to get from Dynkin to monotone class, you use the modified set $\{A \mid A\in M \text{and } A^c \in M\}$, where $M$ is a monotone class and then show that the resulting set is a $\lambda$ system.

Comment: @PhoemueX I'm sorry, I had a typo before. It should be finite disjoint unions of $[u,v)$, not just $[u,v)$. And thank you for the comment on the theorems' equivalence. Maybe something's wrong with the way I defined $\mathcal{P}$ or $\mathcal{L}$...

Comment: You could have noted that all elements $A \in \mathcal{P}$ satisfy that $A$ and $A^c$ satisfiy your criterion (the inequality). Then let $\mathcal{L}' = \mathcal{L} \cap \{A^c \mid A \in \mathcal{L}\}$. It should then not be too hard to show that $\mathcal{L}'$ is a lambda system (trivially closed under complements). Note the two equivalent definitions of lambda systems given here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system#Definitions.

Comment: @PhoemueX Ok, I was able to solve the problem using your hints. Thank you so much for your help and the reference! :)